# Reduce margins (left and right)

Tags: margins

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\oddsidemargin 0in
\topmargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in
\topskip 0in

\title{\textsc{\fbox{Rappel de trigonométrie}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

    \section{\textit{\color{red}Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires}}

Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques: 

\begin{center}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
x       & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6}   &\frac{\pi}{4}   &\frac{\pi}{3}   &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\midrule
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}     &0            &-1 \\ 
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2}     &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1            &0  \\ 
\addlinespace
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1               &\sqrt3          &\infty       &0  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{center}
\par
Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante:
\begin{center}
\fbox{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x) + \sin(x) = 1$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey thanks how did u rewrite it so quickly?

Comment: (I'm rly new to LaTeX btw sry ^^

Comment: Does `\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}` instead of `\oddsidemargin 0in
\topmargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in
\topskip 0in` give you what you want? (To mark the code as code, put the code in the cursor and press the `{}` button.)

Comment: ima try this out

Comment: Thanks it's perfect!

Comment: Also how can I write I) Bla bla bla instead of 1 Bla bla bla for sections? ty

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section})}` before the section(s).

Comment: Well thanks that's exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: And just one last thing and I'll stop bothering you but How can i color the whole secttion including the I) thing

Comment: The quick and dirty way is`\textcolor{red}{\section{Valeurs remarquables et formules
 élémentaires}}`, the more systematic is to use `titlesec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of the discussion in the comments, which I will be happy to delete. Note also that there is the `\boxed` command (provided by the `amsmath` package) for boxed displayed equations.

Observe that I've omitted both `center` wrappers.

Note that there should be no blank lines between text and a displayed equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} % 'amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically
%\usepackage{indentfirst} %not needed if 'babel' is loaded with option 'french'
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\color{red}}
{\Roman{section})}
{1em}
{}

\title{\fbox{\Huge\textsc{Rappel de Trigonométrie}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\section{Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires}

Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques: 
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
x       & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6}   &\frac{\pi}{4}   &\frac{\pi}{3}   &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\midrule
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}     &0            &-1 \\ 
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2}     &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1            &0  \\ 
\addlinespace
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1               &\sqrt3          &\infty       &0  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante:
\[
\boxed{\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\ \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, please, change `\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 1` to `\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1`. And do get rid of the first `center` environment, or @egreg might zap you...

Comment: @Mico You are right!

Comment: Thanks a lot sorry again I’m just really new to LaTeX as you can see ^^